# Cannot find Hotspot under capabilities in xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to connect automatically to a wifi netowrk using `NEHotspotConfiguration`. One of the required steps to use this is to enable Hotspot under capabilities in the target. However I cannot find hotspot under Capabilities. Can anyone help?
[image]

Comment: Does you have the latest xcode?

Comment: Hello, yes 9.2 and building on ios 11.2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

AFAIK, free membership doesn’t have this feature.

You can using account that had enrolled an **Apple Developer Program**,
or manually select a **valid provisioning profile** to solve this issue.

And I think there are hints like

> 13 Capabilities Unavailable
>
> Learn More About Advanced App Capabilities

which would showing below the capabilities list.

You should check account carefully while building a new project.

Comment: Sounds like it, too bad I want to try the feature before enrolling in the program.